# Voximplant Call updated event

Tags: voximplant

I have implemented below method in case upstream operator change caller id information but it is not working properly :-

```
VoxEngine.addEventListener(AppEvents.CallUpdated, (e) => {
    const call = e.call;
    const oldCallerID = e.oldCallFields.callerid; // Get the previous caller ID
    const newCallerID = call.number(); // Get the updated caller ID

    console.log('Caller ID changed from', oldCallerID, 'to', newCallerID);

    // Add your logic to handle the updated caller details
    // This could include storing the information, logging, or taking specific actions based on the change.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not very good idea to use chatgpt and similar tools to generate code. The above snippet will not work because it basically refers to fields, events, etc. that don't exist in the Voximplant platform.

And the task in question has not solution - it's impossible to figure out if upstream carrier changed the callerid of the outbound call.

Comment: If the caller ID is missing/changed from the source number, how will i be able to get recordings based on caller number?

Comment: The caller ID is changed outside Voximplant platform, so you'll be able to get the call recording with the numbers that were available in the scenario.

Comment: in some case of incoming call, callerid is coming blank or is replaced. So is there any other way to do call recording in voximplant when call is connected and fetch caller details.